# How to delete duplicate photos from an iPhoto event?

Tags: photos.app

I did a stupid thing with one Event in iPhoto library. I thought of making a copy of this Event, and I did use the menu duplicate.

Instead of creating another copy of event, it did copies of all the photos inside the existing event. (new to iPhoto usage ;-))

So the big task I have is to delete the possible duplicates of 350 photos. Is there any tool/ option in iPhoto/ apple script etc.. to accomplish task ?

Answer (score 2):

Just because there are duplicates within iPhoto, doesn't mean that iPhoto actually has duplicated the file.  Navigate to `~/Pictures/`.  Right-click on iPhoto Library, show package contents.  Find your event within Originals/<year>/<event name>.  Backup the directory.  Remove the event from iPhoto - I don't know if this removes the actual folder or not, that's why I suggested backing it up first.  Re-add it.  Voila.

Let me know if it has actually duplicated the files.  I know of a great duplicate removal app, but it's not free.

Comment: yes, they are exact duplicates. I did open the iPhoto Library via show package contents, I see a new folder is created with '_2' appended to the original Event folder name. I am guessing if I delete the new folder duplicates will go. Let me know.

Comment: @garikapati - I would; close iPhoto, move the folders with _2 outside of the iPhoto Library, and then rebuild the iPhoto Library.  Do this by holding cmd+opt while launching iPhoto.  It will rebuild the database and should get rid of any anomalies that can be introduced by simply moving those folders away when iPhoto isn't expecting you to.  Let me know if that doesn't fix your problem.  This article may be relevant to you: http://cdevroe.com/notes/iphoto-salbum-dupes/

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mkdir ~/.Trash/iPhoto-Originals
> cd ~/"Pictures/iPhoto Library/Modified/"
> find . -type f -exec mv "../Originals/{}" ~/.Trash/iPhoto-Originals/ \;
> ```

http://osxmactips.blogspot.com/2009/01/delete-duplicate-iphoto-photos.html

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a $7 app called Duplifinder that finds and shows duplicates in your iPhoto Library:
http://www.haystacksoftware.com/duplifinder/

You can view the sets of duplicates, double-click to locate a photo in iPhoto, press Delete to delete a photo from iPhoto. Or just push "Move all duplicates to iPhoto Trash" to clean up.

If you have any questions about it please email me at support@haystacksoftware.com.
- Stefan